# printing out python list from python binary tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, binary-tree

I want to define a function which returns a list of the tree node values. The list is in level order (top to bottom, left to right), if a
child is missing then in its location, "None" is inserted.

This is the Binary Tree implementation

```
class BinaryTree:

def __init__(self, data, left = None, right = None):

    self.left = left
    self.right  = right

def insert_left(self, data):
    self.left = BinaryTree(data, left=self.left)  

def insert_right(self, data):
    self.right = BinaryTree(data, right=self.right)

def set_value(self, val):
    self.key = val

def get_value(self):
    return self.key

def create_string(self, indent):
    string = str(self.key) + '---+'
    if self.left:
        string += '\n(l)' + indent + self.left.create_string(indent + '    ')
    if self.right:
        string += '\n(r)' + indent + self.right.create_string(indent + '    ')
    return string

def __str__(self):
    return self.create_string('  ')

def return_list(self, templist):
    templist.append(self.key)
    if self.left is None:
        templist.append(None)
    else:
        self.left.return_list(templist)
    if self.right is None:
        templist.append(None)
    else:
        self.right.return_list(templist)

def main():    
    tree = BinaryTree(3) 
    tree.insert_left(29)
    tree.insert_right(4)
    right = tree.get_right_subtree()
    left = tree.get_left_subtree()
    left.insert_left(26)
    right.insert_right(2)
    right2 = right.get_right_subtree()
    right2.insert_left(9)
    templist = []
    tree.return_list(templist)
main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the entire .py file If you run this it should work

```
from collections import deque

class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, data, left = None, right = None):
        self.key = data
        self.left = left
        self.right  = right

    def insert_left(self, data):
        self.left = BinaryTree(data, left=self.left)  

    def insert_right(self, data):
        self.right = BinaryTree(data, right=self.right)

    def get_left_subtree(self):
        return self.left

    def get_right_subtree(self):
        return self.right

    def set_value(self, val):
        self.key = val

    def get_value(self):
        return self.key

    def create_string(self, indent):
        string = str(self.key) + '---+'
        if self.left:
            string += '\n(l)' + indent + self.left.create_string(indent + '    ')
        if self.right:
            string += '\n(r)' + indent + self.right.create_string(indent + '    ')
        return string

    def __str__(self):
        return self.create_string('  ')

    def return_list(self, templist):
        templist.append(self.key)
        if self.left is None:
            templist.append(None)
        else:
            self.left.return_list(templist)
        if self.right is None:
            templist.append(None)
        else:
            self.right.return_list(templist)


def return_b_list(tree,templist,queue):
    if tree is None:
        return;
    queue.append(tree)
    while len(queue) !=0:
        node = queue.popleft()
        if node is None:
            templist.append(None)
        else:
            templist.append(node.key)
            queue.append(node.left)
            queue.append(node.right)




def main():    
    tree = BinaryTree(3) 
    tree.insert_left(29)
    tree.insert_right(4)
    right = tree.get_right_subtree()
    left = tree.get_left_subtree()
    left.insert_left(26)
    right.insert_right(2)
    right2 = right.get_right_subtree()
    right2.insert_left(9)
    templist = []
    queue = deque() # you should do a from collections import deque
    return_b_list(tree,templist,queue)
    print tree.create_string(' ')
    print templist

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

you should pass a empty list to this function

```
def return_list(self, templist):
    templist.append(self.key)
    if self.left is None:
        templist.append(None)
    else:
        self.left.return_list(templist)
    if self.right is None:
        templist.append(None)
    else:
        self.right.return_list(templist)
```

after you call this method templist will have the list that you want

Comment: I was going to use this to call tree =BinaryTree(2) 
    tree.insert_left(31)
    tree.insert_right(5)
    right = tree.get_right_subtree()
    left = tree.get_left_subtree()
    left.insert_left(27)
    right.insert_right(1)
    right2 = right.get_right_subtree()
    right2.insert_left(7)

Comment: But return_list has two parameters so what would i use for my second parameter when calling , like return_list(tree,...)

Comment: No this will be a method of class so you call as tree.retrun_list(templist). where templist is an empty list.

Comment: i get this error when i call it AttributeError: 'BinaryTree' object has no attribute 'return_list'

Comment: you should add this method to your class. this will be member method

Comment: tree.return_list(templist)
NameError: name 'templist' is not defined

Comment: is there a way to create a seperate function outside below the class but not part of it. Such as create_tree(tree):

Comment: as i mentioned earlier you should define a empty list before like templist=[] and then call the method tree.return_list(templist)

Comment: do i define this in the main() part ?

Comment: I tried it, doesnt print anything out for some reason :/

Comment: @ Vikas Madhusudana any ideas ?

Comment: I did define it but it printed nothing

Comment: can you provide your main method

Comment: you have to print templist to get the output

Comment: I copied the code and added a print in main() and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are exactly looking for breadth first search then this method might help

```
  def return_b_list(tree,templist,queue):
    if tree is None:
        return;
    queue.append(tree)
    while len(queue) !=0:
        node = queue.popleft()
        if node is None:
            templist.append(None)
        else:
            templist.append(node.key)
            queue.append(node.left)
            queue.append(node.right)
```

How to call? ( this method need not be part of the class)

```
def main():    
    tree = BinaryTree(3) 
    tree.insert_left(29)
    tree.insert_right(4)
    right = tree.get_right_subtree()
    left = tree.get_left_subtree()
    left.insert_left(26)
    right.insert_right(2)
    right2 = right.get_right_subtree()
    right2.insert_left(9)
    templist = []
    queue = deque() # you should do a from collections import deque
    return_b_list(tree,templist,queue)
    print templist
```

Comment: it doesnt seem to work it doesnt give level order traversal

Comment: what is the output you are getting

Comment: [2, 29, 26, None, None, None, 4, None, 2, 9, None, None, None]

Comment: but it should be this:  [2, 29, 4, 26, None, None, 2, None, None, None, None, None, None, 9, None]

Comment: I'm trying to avoid putting the function in the class, and just have it seperate from the class ?

Comment: It should be not part of class I am getting [3, 29, 4, 26, None, None, 2, None, None, 9, None, None, None]

Comment: can you see the code I did ? I been getting the wrong output with that because I took out "self"

Comment: Can I see the exact code you have written in the file and the way you have formatted it please :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a answer but just wanted to add the result that i am getting and the clarification

```
$ python binarayTree.py
3---+
(l) 29---+
(l)     26---+
(r) 4---+
(r)     2---+
(l)         9---+

[3, 29, 4, 26, None, None, 2, None, None, 9, None, None, None]
```

Here is the explanation of result list

```
first level 3
second level 29,4
third level 26, None, None ,2
fourth level None, None,9, None, None, None
```

Comment: your getting this through the def return_list function you provided ?

Comment: I dont understand why I'm getting a different output. I changed the code abit to take out self, and added a tree parameter instead

Comment: something must be different because I copy pasted everything and my outcome is different to yours :/

Comment: No it is not from def return_list it is from return_b_list

Comment: Let me add the py file